# Listen for USB data with usb4java

Tags: java, usb

I'm working on a personal side project with my raspberry pi.  I've decided I wanted to use usb4java as the library to interface with some of my hardware.  I have a real simple goal in mind here, to listen for input from a makey makey in a Java class.  I've managed to build a simple program using usb4java that allows me to init and get the handle for my makey makey.  The problem I have is the following:  I have no idea what my "end points" on the makey makey are.  I don't want to send it data and fry the board.  Does anyone have any experience with usb4java that can explain to me how I can just do a generic listen for data on that USB device?

Comment: You may not want to try to handle it as a raw USB device.  It looks like out of the box it would be an HID input device and so probably already claimed by the kernel - you'd likely get keyboard or mouse events from it.  If you put it in "Arduino mode" then it may well show up as a USB-serial device which you would access as a serial port.

Comment: Even without turning it into "Ardunio mode" I'm still able to claim it.  But, for the sake of figuring it out, lets say I did have to put it into Arduino mode.  I'd still be stuck without knowing my end points and such, yes?

Comment: No, because in Arduino mode you would use operating system's serial API, not the underlying USB one.